# jest + supertest async callback was not invoked

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I finished creating my express server and I'm using Jest + Supertest to test my endpoints and testing all the CRUD operations for my mongoose db. So far I can't even create a new user in the test.

**Code:**

```
//server.spec.js
const supertest = require('supertest');
const server = require('./server');

describe('server.js', () => {
    describe('GET /', () => {
        it('should connect to server responding w/ 200', (done) => {
            return supertest(server)
            .get('/')
            .then(res => {
                expect(res.status).toBe(200);
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    describe('/api/users/', () => {
        it('should create a new user', async () => {
            return await supertest(server)
            .post('/api/users/register')
            .send({ username: "jest", email: "jest@jest.com", password: "jestjest" })
            .set("Accept", "application/json")
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.body)
                expect(res.status).toBe(201)
            })
        })
    });
});
```

**Console output:**

```
FAIL  src/server.spec.js (8.573 s)
  server.js
    GET /
      √ should connect to server responding w/ 200 (231 ms)
    /api/users/
      × should create a new user (5005 ms)

  ● server.js › /api/users/ › should create a new user

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

      17 |         it('should create a new user', async () => {
      18 |             return await supertest(server)
    > 19 |             .post('/api/users/register')
         |         ^
      20 |             .send({ username: "jest", email: "jest@jest.com", password: "jestjest" })
      21 |             .set("Accept", "application/json")
      22 |             .then(res => {

      at new Spec (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Suite.describe (src/server.spec.js:19:9)
      at Suite.Object.<anonymous>.describe (src/server.spec.js:18:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/server.spec.js:6:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.61 s, estimated 9 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.(node:26872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Caught error after test environment was torn down
```

I've attempted different types of solutions but to no success.

**## EDIT ##**
Thank you to @Estus Flask for providing me the answer.
I forgot to add my database.

Comment: There are no mistakes in test code, at least in `should create a new user`, and the error means what it says, there is a timeout. This is specific to your app that wasn't shown. The most common reason for this I've seen is that people forget to connect to Mongoose. If you use it, that's it.

Comment: @Estus Flask, OH MY GOD THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: I had the same issue and in my case the problem was that accidentally I closed the db connection in afterEach() function instead of afterAll()